# javascript adding a parameter on dynamically created button

Tags: javascript

i created a button that will be created dynamically, so the html content of the button is written on javascript string. this is my code:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type='button' value='Apply Now' 
        onclick='pageRedirect('" + entity.ServiceID + "', '" + 
            entity.RecordID + "');'>
    </td>
</tr>
```

this code does not work, particularly on the part where i assigned the parameter. i also tried this code with escape sequence but still the same error.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type='button' value='Apply Now' 
            onclick='pageRedirect(\'" + entity.ServiceID +"\', \'" + 
                entity.RecordID + "\');'>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I don't know what I'm missing. Some help please?

Comment: Your quoting is just wrong in `onclick = 'pageRedirect('" + entity.ServiceID +"', '" + entity.RecordID + "');'`  Assuming `pageRedirect` and `entity` are global symbols, I'm not sure why you don't just use `onclick='pageRedirect(entity.ServiceID,entity.RecordID);'`

Comment: what should be right ?

Comment: See what I added to my previous comment.

Comment: if i remove the single quotes on the assigning of parameters, the console returns this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: @DustineTolete you can get your error from the code highlighting itself on SO.

Comment: @DustineTolete - did you try it exactly how I showed it in my first comment?  When you put a string there, it's just evaluated as javascript text so you don't have to do all that funny quoting and string arithmetic.

Comment: yes i tried it exactly even before asking it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're escaping/closing the wrong quotes. In your code snippet you're actually ending the `onclick` attribute. IE: `onclick='pageRedirect(' ...everything after is now a new attribute`

Try something like the following:

```
"<tr><td><input type = 'button' value = 'Apply Now' onclick = 'pageRedirect(\"" + entity.ServiceID +"\", \"" + entity.RecordID + "\");'></td></tr>"
```

Comment: Why not just `onclick='pageRedirect(entity.ServiceID, entity.RecordID);'`?

Comment: @jfriend00 even i don't know why. i tried it even before asking this question here.

Comment: @DustineTolete - The simpler version works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/EZ8HX/ so there must be something about your page that you aren't showing us.